# Is it possible to weatherproof an indoor couch?

Tags: furniture, weather-resistant

Can an indoor couch, upholstered with fabric, be used on a screened-in porch in the Philadelphia climate (with some proper treatment).

[image]

Comment: Proper treatment will mean not letting it get wet.  Do not think any spray treatments will be good enough.  Will need to protect it from rain/snow getting on it and from humidly/dew.  This probably is a good time to look into outdoor furniture that is made for this.  I imagine you do not want to wrap it up in a heavy plastic sealed bag.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Will you like the results? Probably not. What you have there is a giant sponge for humidity and moisture. Any dampness that gets into it will stay for a long time. To "weatherproof" it, you'll really need to _seal_ it to prevent moisture from getting in and you probably won't like it when you're done doing so.

Comment: If you go to a nearby university (Penn, Temple, ...) and walk down fraternity row, you will see lots of couches on porches. The next year you will also see lots of couches on porches. They are not the same couches...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like moldy couches, sure.

The *proper treatment* to avoid that would look something like replacing all the screens on the porch with sliding glass doors, and making sure they are closed whenever it might be rainy, foggy, misty, etc.

Selling or donating this couch and getting a couch designed for somewhat-outdoor use will be a lot less hassle and expense.